# Enable Web Server Logging With Quota and Retentions through Azure Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm looking for a command in Powershell that can configure additional settings for Web Server Logging:

[image: azure diagnostics]

So far I can turn on diagnostics with the command:

```
Set-AzureWebsite HttpLoggingEnabled 1
```

Are there commands to enable and set retention as well as the quota?

Comment: This is a long shot but did you ever figure this one out? i need to set a storage account rather than the filesystem.

Comment: @DamianStanger Yes, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to Damian's comment, yes, I did solve it!

You'll need to use this configuration block:

```
  # Configuration for enabling diagnostics, quota and retention with retention period.
  $PropertiesObject = @{
    httpLogs = @{
        fileSystem = @{
            enabled = $TRUE;
            retentionInMb = 35;
            retentionInDays = 7;
        }
    }
  }
```

And you'll need to use the `Set-AzureResource` (may be a different cmdlet if you're using ARM):

```
    # Apply the configuration to the web app.
    Set-AzureResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject `
      -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config `
      -ResourceName $ResourceName/logs -OutputObjectFormat New -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
```

One thing I found helpful is using resources.azure.com. I'm not sure what you're looking for exactly, but here are other config blocks I found using that website:

```
"properties": {
    "applicationLogs": {
      "fileSystem": {
        "level": "Off"
      },
      "azureTableStorage": {
        "level": "Off",
        "sasUrl": null
      },
      "azureBlobStorage": {
        "level": "Off",
        "sasUrl": null,
        "retentionInDays": null
      }
    },
    "httpLogs": {
      "fileSystem": {
        "retentionInMb": 100,
        "retentionInDays": 7,
        "enabled": true
      },
      "azureBlobStorage": {
        "sasUrl": null,
        "retentionInDays": 7,
        "enabled": false
      }
```

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what i found myself after digging the docs, its frustrating how little Microsoft documentation there is around this area. i too found the resources.azure.com site useful whilst researching this. Ive got 20 web apps that i needed to do this to, 2 stages each and 3 environments, so glad i didn't have to use the portal to do all 120 sites.